# How do I get a users friendliests?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying to get the friendlists of a logged in user through the graph endpoint "/me/friendlists". I have already added the extended permissions in the Facebook settings with read_friendlists. I tested this out and it returns a empty array. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the code that I am using to get the friendLists:

```
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friendlists" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id results,NSError* error){    
        NSLog(@"%@",results);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no /me/friendlists endpoint for the Graph API. The friend list is a field off of the User object https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Try this endpoint instead: "me?fields=friendlists"

You can also use the graph explorer to try out your queries before coding them up: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Thank you, I guess the tutorial i followed it old. The documentation says that it returns a name and a ids, but somehow I only got a id.

Comment: nevermind, I just copied "me?fields=friendlists" but it should be "/me?fields=friendlists" the slash is somewhat important.

Comment: An alternative way to do this is with FQL `//In my friends list
SELECT name, count, flid, type FROM friendlist
    WHERE owner = me() `